# PowerBI Gateway SAAS Without AD

Tags: powerbi, saas, powerbi-datasource

I already published my report to PBI and the gateway and test the connection of the datasource but when I try to open one of the reports, I am having the error:

> power bi this report couldn't access the data source contact the
> author to have fixed it

I am running everything outside an AD, tried installing the PBI gateway in the same server of the SQL and giving permissions to the NT SERVICE\PBIEgwSERVICE into the Analysis Services instance.

Tried too to map the user account in PBI to the local administrator but didn't work either.

The PBI account is a @onmicrosoft.com.

Any way to work around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Analysis Services is not supported to be without AD.